Ignoring ... as it is not a regular file
I'm seeing the following errors when I try to retrieve updates. I am still able to close it and update. But I would like to clear the actual error. It appears to be linked to the network adapter that I am using with my laptop (brostrend):
W: Ignoring 'brostrend.list' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it is not a regular file
W: http://ppa.launchpad.net/kelebek333/kablosuz/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/npreining:/debian-ubuntu-onedrive/xUbuntu_22.04 ./ InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG B8AC39B0876D807E home:npreining OBS Project <home:npreining@build.opensuse.org>
E: https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/npreining:/debian-ubuntu-onedrive/xUbuntu_22.04 ./ InRelease is not (yet) available (The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG B8AC39B0876D807E home:npreining OBS Project <home:npreining@build.opensuse.org>)


What's the output of LANG=C stat -c '%F' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brostrend.list? If it's  anything other than "regular file" or "symbolic link" then for sure it doesn't belong there (if it's a directory please post the output of ls -la /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brostrend.list); if it says "symbolic link" then plase post the output of LANG=C stat -c '%F' "$(realpath /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brostrend.list)"


An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/npreining:/debian-ubuntu-onedrive/xUbuntu_22.04 ./ InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG B8AC39B0876D807E home:npreining OBS Project <home:npreining@build.opensuse.org>

You have an expired key. Please read these specific steps to resolve this part of your issue: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/discussions/2774
